# Squeeze whitespace to a single space / join lines

Tags: vim, vi

Let's say I copy and paste this code:

```
foo(a,
    b,
    c)
{
    do something;
}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
foo(a, b, c) {
    do something;
}
```

To do so, I need to reduce contiguous whitespace including newlines to a single space character. How can I do this efficiently?

---

My best solution so far is to select the first character on the lower line (the one I want to "bring up") and:

<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>

Bonus points if you can give a way to bring the next line up, and a way to move the current line up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`J`, means "join line". In your case, `4J` on your first line will transform the first snippet into the second one.

Comment: Can't really get more efficient than that!